# Android-How To Parse an Internal JSON file

Tags: android, json, parsing

I want to parse a json file into my Android app. But the json file is going to be into my project folder. I tried to connect a json url and parse that way.

All the sample codes on the internet makes a communication with internet to parse json data. By this way i want to get rid of httpPost, Service Handler class and things like that which provides communication with internet. I think this way it will be easier. How can i do that? Any suggesting link? And will you agree with me about being easy? Am i right?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in your assets folder, then read the file in from assets.  Parse the resulting string.  Its fairly common code.

Comment: Thanks assets is the keyword i guess.

Answer (score 3):

Create a folder named "raw" or whatever name you'd like inside your android project's res directory. Create a new file inside this folder, let's call this "raw_file.json". You can parse this JSON file into your Android app by doing the below:

```
try {
    InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.raw_file);
    byte[] b = new byte[inputStream.available()];
    inputStream.read(b);

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(new String(b));
    String s = jsonObject.getString("someKey");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
} catch (IOException e){
    Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
}
```

Comment: What if i had [ .... ] . I mean JSONArray. how would you land the array in that code?

Comment: JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("key");  JSONObject jsonObjectN = jsonArray.get(indexN); // where N is 0, 1... jsonArray.length()-1  jsonObjectN.getString("theKeyYoureLookingFor");